# Order of execution

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm running into an error which I think is related to the order of execution. When I try to run the following functions together under the `main` function, I get an exception: "Those rows are out of bounds."

```
//copies sheet to another tab 
function copySheet() {  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Sheet1'),  true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:F').activate();  
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Sheet1\'!A1:F').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);  
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Sheet1'), true);  
  sheet.activate();  
};  


//Deletes empty rows from sheet copy  
function removeEmptyRows() {  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Copy of Sheet1');  
  var Avals = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();  
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;  
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows();   
  sh.deleteRows(Alast+1, maxRows-Alast);  
}  


function main() {  
  copySheet();  
  removeEmptyRows();  
}
```

The only reason I can think of is that the functions under `main()` are running in parallel. Since the sheet "Copy of Sheet1" only has 1 row (before running the script), `removeEmptyRows()` function gives the "out of bounds" exception.

Is it because of the order of execution? How to fix the error?

Comment: Hi. This looks like an exact copy of your other question - it was closed because you are being asked to supply some data so that others can try to reproduce the error. That earlier (closed) question takes precedence. Please provide the data required to to re-open that question.

Comment: I had modified the original question but later deleted and reposted it. This is why it looks like an exact copy. Please let me know if you think more information is required.. This is the full code here.

Comment: I'm referring to this question on WebApps [App Script Order of Execution [closed]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/167304/196152).  I can see that you rewrote your question but it (for the moment) "Closed". You can't just create a new question with the exact content - you've got to get the original question re-opened. FWIW, it would be useful to supply some dummy data so that volunteers can try to reproduce the error.